# Android JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json

I'm new in android. I'm trying to get json but I got this error.
I trying following this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

I already search the solution, but I still don't get it how to use the JSONArray.

Here is my Json example

```
[{"id":"152","category_id":"14","item_name":"Restaurant1","cuisine_id":"3","cuisine_name":"Chinese"},{"id":"161","category_id":"14","item_name":"Restaurant10","cuisine_id":"17","cuisine_name":"Middle Eastern"},{"id":"153","category_id":"14","item_name":"Restaurant2","cuisine_id":"17","cuisine_name":"Middle Eastern"},{"id":"154","category_id":"14","item_name":"Restaurant3","cuisine_id":"7","cuisine_name":"American"},{"id":"155","category_id":"14","item_name":"Restaurant4","cuisine_id":"3","cuisine_name":"Chinese"},{"id":"156","category_id":"14","item_name":"Restaurant5","cuisine_id":"8","cuisine_name":"Coffee"},{"id":"157","category_id":"14","item_name":"Restaurant6","cuisine_id":"8","cuisine_name":"Coffee"},{"id":"158","category_id":"14","item_name":"Restaurant7","cuisine_id":"17","cuisine_name":"Middle Eastern"},{"id":"159","category_id":"14","item_name":"Restaurant8","cuisine_id":"6","cuisine_name":"Indonesian"},{"id":"160","category_id":"14","item_name":"Restaurant9","cuisine_id":"3","cuisine_name":"Chinese"}]
```

And Here the class

```
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetRestaurant extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Attractions.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                restaurant = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEM_NAME);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < restaurant.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = restaurant.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_CUISINE_NAME);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_CUISINE_NAME, id);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    restaurantList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Attractions.this, restaurantList,
                R.layout.attractionslayout, new String[] { TAG_ITEM_NAME, TAG_CUISINE_NAME }, new int[] { R.id.item_name,
                        R.id.cuisine_name});

     // Assign adapter to ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Thanks Before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Your response starts with `JSONArray`

```
[                ==> JSONArray
    {            ==> JSONObject
```

Change this..

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

// Getting JSON Array node
restaurant = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEM_NAME);
```

to

```
restaurant = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its works. Now I know the problem.
So If its start with "{" I can use my old code?

Comment: @user3561934 Ya you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not json object , it is json array because the string are start via third bracket

so, try this

```
restaurant = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

you do not need to convert it as a josn object,

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```